# Jenkins not able to locate git on my laptop. The recommended git tool is: NONE

Tags: git, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-build-flow

I have specified the path of git in both Configure System and Global Tool configuration in jenkins but still jenkins is showing "The recommended git tool is: NONE" in console output.

Comment: Which OS? Where is local Git installed? Where in Configure System? Where in Global Tool Configuration? Which type of Jenkins project? Which configuration? Which Console Output apart from this one line? We're all volunteers here. The professional mind readers all have shows in Las Vegas.

Comment: I have the same issue. 
I went to configuration of node and section: "Tool Locations" where I added "Git (Default)" and provided path to Git installation on Jenkins node: "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\Git.exe". 
But still see the same error at the beginning of the job execution.

Answer (score 0):

Try use

tools {
git 'Git'
}

before te steps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).